# Xamarin Forms - Android button using relative layour from Resources/Layout

Tags: android, xamarin, android-relativelayout

Visual Studio 2017
So I have an app, IOS & Android which uses Xamarin Forms.
I have downloaded as RelativeLayout file into resources/Layouts.

IS there a way I can use this layout in a Custom button renderer?

All our forms are in the Xamarin project so I can't just include it in a fragment.

Am I flogginga dead horse by trying to fudge using it in a customer renderer?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using an Android RelativeLayout vs a Forms'-based one?

Comment: I need to show a button which will be different for IOS & Android and actually follows brand guidelines of the relative third party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view renderer for your custom button. Then replace it with your native layout:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomButton), typeof(CustomButtonRenderer))]
namespace App.Droid
{
    public class CustomButtonRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomButton, Android.Views.View>
    {
        Context _context;
        public CustomButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomButton> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                SetNativeControl(getView());
            }
        }

        Android.Views.View getView()
        {
            return LayoutInflater.From(_context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.custom_layout, null);
        }
    }
}
```

At last you can consume the custom control in XAML like:

```
<StackLayout>
    <local:CustomButton />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: You sir are a star!
You have made that look extremely straightforward and it seems to work for me.
Thank you.
I'm new to mobile dev and I do get confused between XAML & fragments and thge like  but I am getting there.

Comment: @AntDC Glad to help you. And feel free to ask questions here.